# wp_mail_from is ignored

Tags: email

I'm setting the specific "from" address using wp_mail_from.

I've verified that it's actually called and I'm passing a legit me@domain.com email address.

But by the time it hits /var/log/mail.log, the from address is "localaccount@my.hosting.server.com".

In the wp_mail( ) call I'm even setting the headers 'From:....'. Doesn't matter, it's still ignored.

I'm not sure this is a wp thing, but I've checked all my php settings and I'm not finding anything that would indicate that it forces the "from" of every email.

For now I've used a generic map in postfix to convert the local account email address to a legit "from" address. But the problem is I need some emails in wordpress to be sent from one address and other emails sent from another.

I have it setup in wp_mail_from to set the correct from address, only it's ignored completely somewhere along the way, just not sure what's doing me in.

Ideas?

Comment: you may  have ssl server kindly try to add existing mail  in from option

Comment: Try sending the email through a remote server such as Gmail to see if the same results occur. It could be the mail app is changing the `From` header. http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-send-email-in-wordpress-using-the-gmail-smtp-server/

Comment: from mail  is that  the  existing mail in your account  or any server kindly check if that not exists it will not work on ssl server

Comment: presently you are passing the defout   name@yourdomeain.com that is not already exists mail